# asp.net membership for two projects in a solution

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership

I have two web projects both using the same database and they are in the same solution.
One of them using asp.net membership.I want also include the other one.How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the second app to use the same membership database.  Change the `applicationName` property of the membership provider config in your web.config to something different from the first app.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this for nested applications recently.  Its not too difficult.

In addition to Kyle's points, you need to:

- make sure the the machineKeys are the same for both web applications
- configure loginUrl's to resolve to the same absolute path
- if you're using cookies you need to make sure that the domain is set to a value available to both web applications
- also for cookies, if your web applications are nested at diferent levels in a domain make sure that the path attribute is set to "/"

See [this blog post](http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2012/03/cross-domain-forms-authentication-with.html) for more detail.